# Origin has been blocked by CORS policy - web.config contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"

Tags: iis, cors, web-config

I'm having the following issue when trying to use some components of a web-app:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://XXXX:8091/attributetree/getattributetreeitems/2?_=1602596764050'
> from origin 'http://XXXX:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
> does not have HTTP ok status.

I have set the following in the web.config:

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

but I keep getting the CORS origin blocked error.

When I start the application in localhost (local build) it works without issue, but when I put it on the IIS on the server (IIS6) I get the error. the web-app consists of 2 webserver (one for app and one for service).

Comment: What is your application? asp.net core? or other?

Answer (score -1):

Your solution works for IIS7, for IIS6 please do :

- Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager
- Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to Properties
- Change to the HTTP Headers tab
- In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add
- Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name
- Enter * as the header value
- Click Ok twice

More [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled)

Comment: I have done that as well and still the same issue :(